# Avoiding use of eval in raphael.sketchpad function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, raphael, eval

I have the following code which works as expected:

```
                var svg_height = $("#svg-container").height();
                var svg_width = $("#svg-container").width();
                var name = "sketchpad";

    eval("window." + name + "= Raphael.sketchpad('"
                                + "svg-container" + "',{" + " width:"
                                + svg_width + "," + "height: " +           svg_height
                                + "," + "editing: true," + " });");
```

However I want to avoid using eval for security reasons.
I tried the following but it does not work

```
window.sketchpad = Raphael.sketchpad("'svg-container',{width:"+ svg_width +",height:"+ svg_height +", editing: true}");
```

Can this be solved using JSON. If yes, how?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I know nothing about Raphael, but just translating your `eval` code.

```
window[name] = Raphael.sketchpad("svg-container", {
                                        width: svg_width,
                                        height: svg_height,
                                        editing: true
                 });
```

The function you had is nearly there, just has a couple erroneous quotes messing it up.

Answer (score 2):

This should work too.

```
window.sketchpad = Raphael.sketchpad("svg-container", {
                                        width: svg_width,
                                        height: svg_height,
                                        editing: true
                 });
```

There is no need to use the name variable here.